# Create new div on mouse idle with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new div every time my mouse goes idle for 4 seconds. The div should continue to increase in size as you idle longer. So far nothing seems to be showing up on my page? I put my jquery in a snippet below.
Many thanks for the help.

```js
   
var clickTimer;

// make a counter
var n = 0;

$('body').mouseup(function() {
  clearTimeout(clickTimer);
  // Clear interval
  return false;

}).mousedown(function() {

  // Set interval
  clickTimer = window.setInterval(function() {

    // add to n every 4 milliseconds
    n++;

    // tranform circle's css every 4 milliseconds
    $('#stoppedcircle').css('transform', 'scale(' + n / 10 + ')');

  }, 4);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: kindly post relevant html and css for `stoppedcircle`

Comment: What is `initialize()`? Also, two things: First, because you're clearing an interval, you'll probably want `clearInterval` instead of `clearTimeout`. Second, you should look up `$('#stoppedcircle')` once and store it at as a variable. As of right now, you're doing an identical DOM lookup every 4 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var clickTimer;

// make a counter
var n = 0;

$('body').mousemove(function() {
  clearTimeout(clickTimer);
  // Clear interval
  return false;

}).click(function() {
  // Set interval
  clickTimer = window.setInterval(function() {

    // add to n every 4 milliseconds
    n++;

    // tranform circle's css every 4 milliseconds
    $('#stoppedcircle').css('transform', 'scale(' + n / 10 + ')');

  }, 4);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stoppedcircle">stoppedcircle</div>
```

please use 'mousemove' and 'click' event

Answer (score 0):

How about using keyframes?

```js
$(function() {
  var anime = 'anime-page-cover';
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var delay = 4 * 1000;
  setInterval(function() {
    overlay.addClass(anime);
  }, delay);
  var hideOverlay = function() {
    overlay.removeClass(anime);
  };
  $(document).on('mousemove', hideOverlay).on('input', hideOverlay).on('click', hideOverlay);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.anime-page-cover {
  animation: page-cover 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes page-cover {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2000, 2000);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='overlay anime-page-cover'></div>
  <p>There goes my page content</p>
</body>
```

Comment: That could work. How would I get to create it at the mouse's position and create a new circle while saving the old ones? Many thanks.